# Descobrir porcentagem em números repetidos - Python - Estatística

Tags: python

Bom dia Pessoal. 
Preciso resolver um problema de Estatística.
Porém estou com dificuldade para encontrar a porcentagem dos números agrupados que se repetem. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Agradeço desde já, segue código:

```
import os
import math
import numpy as quartil

print("\nOs dados abaixo referem-se ao número de alunos formados no curso técnico da ETEC entre 1991 e 2015."
      "\nConstrua a tabela (1) de Distribuição de Frequencias com Freq. Absoluta, Freq. Relativa e Freq. Acumulada."
      "\n")

Dados = []
Dados = raw_input('Entre com os dados, separando por espaço: ').split(';')
print(Dados)
Dados.sort()
print("Rol: ", Dados)
var = quartil.array([Dados])
# quartiles
form2       =   [9,10,11,12,13,14]

#Achar repeticoes
repeticoes =[]
for i in Dados:
    if Dados.count(i) > 1 and i not in repeticoes:
        repeticoes.append(i)
        #porcentagem = int((repeticoes.count(i)*100)/sum(repeticoes))
        #porcentagem.append(i)
print(repeticoes)
#print(porcentagem)

#Achar porcentagem das repeticoes
porcentagem =[]
for i in repeticoes:
    if repeticoes.count(i) > 1 and i not in porcentagem:
        porc = ((repeticoes.count(i)*100)/sum(int(repeticoes)))
        porcentagem.append(porc)
print(porc)
```

Comment: Tá, qual que é a sua dúvida?

Comment: O que são "números agrupados que se repetem" e que porcentagem seria essa?

Comment: Eu preciso encontrar a porcentagem equivalente aos números que estão se repetindo no rol, exemplo: 9;8;9;7;2;1
9 repetiu 2 vezes 
8 1 vez
7 1 vez
1 1 vez
Através desta repetição, eu preciso descobrir a porcentagem equivalente a esses números, supondo que o total seja a qtde que o usuário digitar.

Comment: Estou tentando desta forma:

import os
import math
import numpy as quartil

print("\nOs dados abaixo referem-se ao número de alunos formados no curso técnico da ETEC entre 1991 e 2015."
      "\nConstrua a tabela (1) de Distribuição de Frequencias com Freq. Absoluta, Freq. Relativa e Freq. Acumulada."
      "\n")
Dados = []
Dados = raw_input('Entre com os dados, separando por ponto e virgula: ').split(';')
Dados.sort()
print("")
print('Rol: ', ';'.join(Dados))

Dados.sort()
import collections
counter = collections.Counter(Dados)
print('N: ', counter.values())

Answer (score 1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from collections import Counter

Dados = []
Dados = raw_input('Entre com os dados, separando por espaço: ').split(' ')
print(Dados)

'''Calcular repeticoes, criando um dicionário com o Counter
Counter usa cada elemento único como chave e sua respectiva
quantidade de repetições como valor.'''
repeticoes = Counter(Dados)
print(repeticoes)

#Calcular porcentagem das repeticoes
t = len(Dados) #Quantidade de dados informada na entrada
'''Utilização do Counter "repeticoes" para gerar uma lista
com todas as porcentagens obtidas no map.
repeticoes[x] retorna o valor da chave x no dicionario.'''
porcentagem = list(map(lambda x: repeticoes[x]*100/t, repeticoes))

print(porcentagem)
```

Comment: Pode [edit] sua resposta e adicionar uma explicação da lógica implementada?

Comment: Valeu Vinicius, era isso mesmo que eu precisava! :)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado pela solicitação.

Comment: +1. ou ... `percentagem = [repeticoes[x]*100/t for x in repeticoes]`